# SpringIntegration message size to big, how to split

Tags: size, jms, message, spring-integration

I have a SprintIntegration system with a JMS endpoint. The size limit for messages is 4mb. I have results which are larger then that, how do I get SI to split that up into several messages?

/A

Answer (score 2):

In Spring Integration, you can use a [Splitter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/docs/2.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/#overview-endpoints-splitter) to split your messages to not exceed e.g. 4MB.

```xml
<int:splitter id="splitter" 
              ref="splitterBean" 
              method="split" 
              input-channel="inputChannel" 
              output-channel="outputChannel" />

<beans:bean id="splitterBean" class="your.MessageSplitter"/>
```

or by using a `@Splitter` annotation.

When a message comes in to the splitter, you would apply the splitting logic inside `your.MessageSplitter`, and return a `List<YourMessage>`:

```java
public class MessageSplitter {

    public List<YourMessage> split( HugeMessage hugeMessage ) {

        List nicelySizedMessages = new ArrayList<YourMessage>();

        // splitting logic... that would parse "hugeMessage" and split it to
        // nicelySizedMessages.add( ... ) "YourMessage"s

        return nicelySizedMessages;
    }
}
```

Spring Integration would take this list and would forward `YourMessage`s from the list one by one.